# How to hide everything in list then showed the filtered items

Tags: javascript, animation, vue.js, filtering, css-animations

I am doing a filtered list with vue [here](https://codepen.io/villagelukaschen/pen/byBzZG) using a computed function

```
filteredList() {
   return this.list.filter((item) => {
     if(!this.currentCategory) return true;
     return item.categories.indexOf(this.currentCategory) != -1;
  })
}
```

The animation right now is quite smart and doesn't animate the items that's not changing and even animating the moving list positions.

However I just want a simple fade all out then fade selected data in.

is this possible in vue?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: you would use Vue's HTML `<transition>` wrapper with `name="fade"` and `mode="out-in"`